# Gatling Gradle plugin not including transitive dependencies

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

I am using the [official Gatling Gradle plugin](https://gatling.io/docs/current/extensions/gradle_plugin/) in my Scala project and I am seeing an issue where dependencies included like

```
dependencies {
    gatling "LibraryA"
}
```

are not including transitive dependencies. That is, I have a Gatling simulation class that extends a class from `LibraryB` which `LibraryA` depends on. However, when I try to run the simulation, I get an error like

```
Symbol 'type ClassFromTheTransitiveDependency' is missing from the classpath.
```

When I look at the Gradle dependencies, I see the `LibraryB` as a dependency of `LibraryA`. My IDE (IntelliJ) also recognizes it when clicking through the code.

I've tried searching through the [single page of documentation for the plugin](https://gatling.io/docs/current/extensions/gradle_plugin/), but I don't see anything helpful there. Is this just not supported or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance, and please excuse my Gradle/build mediocrity if it's something simple!

Answer (score 1):

Your post is very incomplete in the sense that there's no way to investigate and help you based on the information you've provided.
Typically, you should provide a way to reproduce your issue, see http://sscce.org.

Here's what I did:

1. clone the [official demo project](https://github.com/gatling/gatling-gradle-plugin-demo)
2. added a dependency to OkHttp (that depends transitively on okio and kotlin)
3. added code using OkHttp in the sample simulation
4. ran `./gradlew gatlingRun`

```
dependencies {
    gatling 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
}
```

```scala
  import okhttp3._
  val client = new OkHttpClient()
  val request = new Request.Builder().url("https://gatling.io").build
  println(client.newCall(request).execute().body.string())
```

Everything works just fine, so the issue is most likely on your side and not with gatling-gradle-plugin. I would recommend starting from the official sample and adding pieces one by one until you figure out which one breaks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry I couldn't give a better reproducible example; it's a bit difficult to do so because the dependency issue is via a private/internal library. One difference between your example and mine is that my code directly uses a class from one of the transitive dependencies. It looks like here you are only using the first-level dependency on OkHttp in your example.

Comment: Try doing the same thing as I did. You have all the tools in your hands.